Maui .NET 8 ANDROID Modify the color of a section of an SVG image
I'm working on a .NET 8 MAUI project and I have encountered the following issue. The app has different types of users, and based on the user, it changes its primary color at runtime. This is to make the app visually distinct for each type of user.
The problem arises with SVG images used in the app, which have sections that display the primary color. For example, an image of a person might have their shirt in the primary color. This section should change color based on the user, as I mentioned earlier.
In MAUI, for the Android platform, I understand that images are processed in PNG format. I've managed to keep the images in SVG format by storing them in the Resources -> Raw folder and setting their Build Action to MauiAsset.
The approach I'm trying to use for changing the color is via SkiaSharp, which seemed to be the simplest option I found. However, it is not working as expected.
The code I can provide is:
private async void LoadAndModifySvg()
{
    // Path to the original SVG file
    string originalSvgFileName = "man_and_car.svg";

    // Read SVG content
    string svgContent = await ReadSvgFileAsync(originalSvgFileName);

    // Replace the color #F27B13 with #0000FF
    svgContent = Regex.Replace(svgContent, @"#F27B13", "#0000FF", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    // Load the SVG content into SKSvg
    _svg = new SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg.SKSvg();

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(svgContent)))
    {
        _svg.Load(stream);
    }

    // Update the view
    CanvasView.InvalidateSurface();
}

private void CanvasView_PaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
{
    if (_svg == null)
        return;

    var canvas = e.Surface.Canvas;
    canvas.Clear(SKColors.White);

    // Adjust the size and position of the SVG on the canvas
    var scale = Math.Min(e.Info.Width / _svg.Picture.CullRect.Width,
                         e.Info.Height / _svg.Picture.CullRect.Height);
    canvas.Scale((float)scale);

    // Draw the SVG
    canvas.DrawPicture(_svg.Picture);
}

// Method to read the SVG file as text
private async Task<string> ReadSvgFileAsync(string fileName)
{
    using (var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(fileName))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
}

From the XAML side, I have:
    <skia:SKCanvasView x:Name="CanvasView" PaintSurface="CanvasView_PaintSurface" 
                       HeightRequest="450"
                       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1.1,1"
                        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                       ZIndex="0"/>

I would appreciate it if someone could help me. The goal is to modify the color of a specific section of an SVG image in MAUI .NET 8. Thank you.

Using regex on an xml document is asking for trouble.

I understand that it is not the best, but this expression works to modify the color used in my SVG. Do you think there is a better way? Could you contribute to the solution of my problem perhaps?

My favourite approach to solving this problem is to invest in Path and Path markup syntax which appears to be inspired by SVG path syntax.

Consider the following SVG where car, man head, and man body has been separated into different sections with different colors. Because of limitations in .NET MAUI Path, I limit each SVG path to the following:

Use only one move command, "M".
If "Z" is used, include it at most once at the end of the path.
Use only fill; set stroke to "none".
Solid objects are defined by clockwise polygons.
Objects with holes are defined by a combination of clockwise polygons (for the outer polygon) and anti-clockwise polygons (for the inner polygon holes) connected by lines.

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32">

<!-- Car -->
<path stroke="none" fill="skyblue" d="
M 0.8 30
v -10
l 4 -9.5
h 16
l 4 9.5
v 10
h -4.3
v -3
h -15.4
v 3
h -4.3
l 2.5 -5.5
h 5
v -3
h -5
v 3
l -2.5 5.5
l 16.7 -5.5
h 5
v -3
h -5
v 3
l -16.7 5.5
l 2.5 -11.5
h 19
l -3 -7
h -13
l -3 7
l -2.5 11.5
"/>

<!-- Man Head -->
<path stroke="none" fill="peru" d="
M 25.2 2
a 3.5 3.5 0 0 1 0 7
a 3.5 3.5 0 0 1 0 -7
"/>

<!-- Man Body -->
<path stroke="none" fill="navy" d="
M 22 9.5
h 7
l 3 7
a 1.3 1.3 0 0 1 -2.5 1
l -.8 -1.1
v 12
a 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 -3 0
v -8
h -0.5
v 8
a 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 -3 0
v -12
l -.8 1.1
a 1.3 1.3 0 0 1 -2.5 -1
l 3 -7
"/>
</svg>

Which I constructed using my Online SVG Editor.
Then, I convert this to Grid and Path in .NET MAUI by adding a sequence M 0 0 L 32 32 L 0 0 to the start of each Path so that they will simulate the viewBox="0 0 32 32":
<Grid HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100">
    <!--  Car  -->
    <Path
        Aspect="Uniform"
        Data="M 0 0 L 32 32 0 0 0.8 30 v -10 l 4 -9.5 h 16 l 4 9.5 v 10 h -4.3 v -3 h -15.4 v 3 h -4.3 l 2.5 -5.5 h 5 v -3 h -5 v 3 l -2.5 5.5 l 16.7 -5.5 h 5 v -3 h -5 v 3 l -16.7 5.5 l 2.5 -11.5 h 19 l -3 -7 h -13 l -3 7 l -2.5 11.5"
        Fill="SkyBlue"
        Stroke="Transparent" />

    <!--  Man Head  -->
    <Path
        Aspect="Uniform"
        Data="M 0 0 L 32 32 0 0 25.2 2 a 3.5 3.5 0 0 1 0 7 a 3.5 3.5 0 0 1 0 -7"
        Fill="Peru"
        Stroke="Transparent" />

    <!--  Man Body  -->
    <Path
        Aspect="Uniform"
        Data="M 0 0 L 32 32 0 0 22 9.5 h 7 l 3 7 a 1.3 1.3 0 0 1 -2.5 1 l -.8 -1.1 v 12 a 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 -3 0 v -8 h -0.5 v 8 a 1.5 1.5 0 0 1 -3 0 v -12 l -.8 1.1 a 1.3 1.3 0 0 1 -2.5 -1 l 3 -7"
        Fill="Navy"
        Stroke="Transparent" />
</Grid>

The Aspect="Uniform" will ensure that the vector graphics will scale.
From this point onwards, it would be easy to replace the hard-coded colors with property bindings so that the colors can change for different users.
